# Access SQL ignore warning about type conversion

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I want to insert some values from a table to another in a sql query.
**But**
My tables don't have the same format in the fields, for instance I ask to transfert a text to a numeric.
It asks me whether or not I want to change the fields type inside my destination table.
**I don't want this warning box to appear**, I want it to automatically convert the type without asking the user.

Most of all, I **don't want to change the SQL Query** to include **cdbl()** , **IsNumeric()** or other stuffs

My code looks like

```
strSQL = "Delete * FROM DestinationTable;"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

strSQL = "INSERT INTO DestinatonTable(Month, Date, Number1, Name, ShortName, Partner, Number2 .... and so on .....)"
strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT StartTable.F1, StartTable.F2, StartTable.F3, ...... and so on ..."
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM StartTable WHERE (IsNumeric([F14])<>0);"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Thank you all for reading and help

Comment: at the beginning the query is Delete * FROM DestinationTable.... it seems like I can't edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [turning warnings off](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/disable-type-conversion-error-messages-t1641802.html) before you run the query

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
' do stuff here
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: @Kingpin It is nearly always better to use `Set db = CurrentDB` ↵ `db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError` rather than playing around with SetWarnings, which will turn off warnings for all instances of Access, so it must be turned back on immediately, something that is quite easy to forget. You are also suppressing all warnings, including some you may have wished to see.

Comment: Downvoted in agreement with @Remou's criticism of turning off notifications. The other problem with doing so is that you may end up with part of your SQL update succeeding, but you really don't know which part -- that would mean you've corrupted your data!